# Selectionsort function but with operator

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a Selectionsort but this time takes an Operator and according to it do the sorting, for example

```
*Main> ssort (<) [2,8,4,6,3,9,7] [2,3,4,6,7,8,9]
*Main> ssort (>) [2,8,4,6,2,6,7] [9,8,7,6,4,3,2]
```

Here is the code that I wrote

```
ssort _ [] = []
ssort f (x:xs) = f x : ssort rest
    where val = f x xs 
          rest = delete val xs
```

now the thing is even if the operator is (>) the numbers are gonna be added in the first.
and the error is

```
Couldn't match type `t -> [t] -> t' with `[t]'
      Expected type: [t] -> [t]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, always add type signatures to you functions. *Before* you define them. This make is much clearer what you're doing, not only to others reading your code but also to yourself. So, if the default sort was

```
sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
```

then now you don't require `Ord a` anymore (because the comparison function is user-supplied, rather than inferred from the global instance), but you do require that comparison. The type of `(<)` and `(>)` is `Ord a => a -> a -> Bool`. Again we don't care about the `Ord` anymore, but `a -> a -> Bool` is still right. I.e.

```
ssort :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

...actually, because you're using `delete`, you still need `Eq`:

```
ssort :: Eq a => (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

...though I'd remard that this wouldn't really be necessary.

Now that you have two parameters, your clauses should take both, i.e. look like

```
ssort (...) (...) = (...)
```

The first one is still right:

```
ssort _ [] = []
```

but now to the interesting one:

```
ssort f (x:xs) = f x : ssort rest
```

Ok, `f x` doesn't make sense here. You want a *value* here, but you've partially applied the *comparison function*. The comparison function will only ever give you comparison results, i.e. booleans, but even that requires supplying two arguments.

I think you actually meant to write

```
ssort f (x:xs) = val : ssort rest
```

which is in fact a good attempt – if we define `val` right. But

```
       val = f x xs
```

clearly doesn't cut it. `f` would simply tell you which of two values is greater, but here you're giving it a whole list. What you *could* do is, see if `x` is `f`-lesser than *all* of the values in the list

```
  where isxLeast = all (f x) xs
```

Ok, so what if it is least? That's the easy case, because then `val` should simply be `x`, right? The following definition expresses that and will at least typecheck:

```
ssort _ [] = []
ssort f (x:xs) = val : ssort rest
 where val
        | all (f x) xs  = x
       rest = delete val xs  -- actually unnecessary in this case,
                             -- because val=x is already split off
```

Problem is, it *only* works if `x` is indeed the least element, and then in the recursion again, and again. In other words, it works only if the list is already sorted anyway!

What you need to do is of course provide the right `val` if it's *not* at the head of the list. So, first we might as well ditch the pattern-matching on the list head:

```
ssort f xs = val : ssort rest
 where val = findLeastOf f xs
       rest = delete val xs

findLeastOf :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> a
findLeastOf f (x:xs)
  | all (f x) xs  = x
  | otherwise     = _
```

You should be able to complete this yourself. (Note that if you recurse on `xs` in `findLeastOf` it will be very inefficient, *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>), making the complexity of the sort *O*(*n*<sup>3</sup>). But maybe that shouldn't worry you right now.)